# Is there another way to call this function besides using php's eval?

Tags: php, eval, anonymous-function

So there's a php function in a database field. Here's what it looks like:

```
'$put_fname_fn = function($filename) {
    return $filename.'.Z';
};'
```

I'm executing it like this:

```
$code = fetchFromDatabase(); // Get the function string
eval($code);
$put_fname_fn('MYFILE.TXT'); // Convert it to MYFILE.TXT.Z
```

Is there a more graceful way to call the user function? I try to avoid using eval but I don't another way to do this.

Comment: What's wrong with `eval` here? If functions, that you are going to execute, are not hard-coded, but come from uncertain sources like database, you are doomed anyway.

Comment: If you need eval, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: `eval` should be avoided because it leads to executing arbitrary code. Executing arbitrary code with something other than `eval` would not be any better.

Comment: @Juhana The code that is being eval'd is not arbitrary. If there is arbitrary code found in the database then there's a bigger problem. Anyway, I'm reconsidering the design here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no other way to evaluate code in PHP. (You could write the code to a file and `include` it, but that's just a hidden `eval`.)

Still you should probably reconsider your application design. Evaluating code from the database is a ***VERY BIG SECURITY RISK***: If your database is compromised (using a simple and common SQL injection attack) you at the same time give the attacker **arbitrary PHP code execution**.

Comment: `There is no over way to evaluate code in PHP` in this particular case, code could be tokenized, taken only needed parts and evaluated using `create_function`, but that still is not going to help anyone.

Comment: The spec is to munge the filename anyway a client might request. I'm not sure how else to do that. So, what I'm going to do is define the function in the code base then eval only a single statement from the database like "return $filename.'.Z';". The statement is considered tainted until it passes a few tests.